# Postgres multiregion active-active setup AWS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is it possible to achieve active/active multi-region (atleast us-east and us-west) on AWS managed postgres (not the aurora flavor)? Custom managed Postgres cluster might also be acceptable solution.

Questions are welcome. I'm not sure what other information I can provide other than the requirement that the ask is to have postgres run in multiregion active-active configration.

Comment: No, Amazon RDS does not provide multi-region deployments for PostgreSQL. You'd have to provision, configure and manage it yourself rather than using Amazon RDS. Can I ask... _WHY_ do you want to go multi-region active-active?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Client consider only active-active as true HA configuration. I'm sure if we manage ourselves, it will add a lot of overhead. Although we don't have very high traffic, I'm still concerned that with active-active configuration, any query that ends up running cross-region, will have high latency.

Comment: People from traditional IT often don't understand the concept of an AZ. You could try explaining to them that an AZ is a **separate datacenter** with different power, internet and physical location. Running a system as multi-AZ will have all (?) the benefits of traditional HA and DR, but with the added benefit that AWS can totally manage the multi-AZ deployment (eg Amazon RDS running servers across multiple AZs). I'd suggest pushing-back on their requirements to confirm that they _really_ have a use-case for requiring multiple regions -- _especially_ if they want them to be active-active!